# PHP POST is not filled

Tags: php, html, post

I am having a problem with a website I have to create. When I call the POST with the right key I dont get the value back. I think the error is that my POST does not get filled.

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;
```

This line is on top of the coding and gives the right id back, I checked that via an echo.

```
<form method="POST" action="Index.php">
<input type="hidden" name="Entryid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
<a type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-success" href="Index.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="cursor: pointer;">Löschen</a>
</form>
```

Here I put the value of id into the key "Entryid" and switch to "Index.php" when I click on a button.
Inside of "Index.php" I try to get the value like that.

```
$id = isset($_POST['Entryid']) && is_numeric($_POST['Entryid']) ? (int) $_PST['Entryid'] : 0;
```

Here the value of id is probably not set and if I check it via echo the output is the 0.
Where do you think my error is?

Comment: just print_r($_POST) and see what you get!

Comment: @AliGhalambaz it prints "Array ( ) 0"

Comment: it means nothing posted! read new answers they are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're using an `<a>`-tag as the button, and not an `input`.

So change this line:

```
<a type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="cursor: pointer;">Löschen</a>
```

to this:

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-success" style="cursor: pointer;" value="Löschen" />
```

The error occurs, because you've made an `<a>` with a `href`, - which means that you're not submitting a form to the destination, - but instead just linking it (with a regular get-request without any additional parameters). [This page](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) explains a bit about it (the section about 'The Method Attribute').

---

But as Ali said. Try on your index.php-page, to write:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

And see what you get, to see if your variable is defined.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked and the id is POSTed right, but now the button is not clickable and a second one appeared to the left of it with "Senden" text which more or less translates to submit. What do you think causes that error? But really thank you so far.

Comment: @ErikaAnhalt You should close the `input`. `<input .... />` If the `a` was styled correctly you alternatively could use use JS to make it process the form. I prefer using the `input` though because if JS is disabled (less likely today) it is not going to process correctly.

Comment: Maybe it's because of the `data-toggle` and `data-target`-attributes. I've just updated my answer (removing them), - and also doing what @user3783243, said (which I forgot to add before). So try and copy-paste the updated answer in, and see what happens...?

Comment: Thank you very very much. You dont know how much you helped right now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an `a` to submit. That doesn't process the form. It just links to the page. Use:

```
<input type="submit" ...
```

and style it as needed.

The `type` of an `a` is not for how it processes a form, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a.

> Specifies the media type in the form of a MIME type for the linked URL. It is purely advisory, with no built-in functionality.